# Errors when using glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I am compiling a `.tex` file with TeXmaker, but it's still generating errors.
In fact, I use the `glossaries` package but when I add a `newglossaryentry`, the compilation ends with errors.
This is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{sk001}
\title{My title}

\usepackage[style=long, nonumberlist, toc, xindy, nowarn, nomain, section=chapter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{iai}{%
name={IAI},%
description={Institut Africain d'Informatique}%
type=\newacronym
}

\begin{document}
\titlepage

\newpage

L'Institut Africain d'Informatique(\gls{iai}) est un établissement d'enseignement supérieur.

\printglossary


\end{document}
```

This is the displayed error in the log:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\glsdefaulttype
l.50 }
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary type '\glsdefaulttype ' has not been defin
ed.
See the glossaries package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.50 }
You need to define a new glossary type, before making entries in it
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\glsdefaulttype
l.50 }
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\acronymtype` be used instead of `\newacronym`?

Comment: You are using `nomain` option so no default glossary type is defined... Did you mean to add the `acronym` option?

Comment: I get `! Package glossaries Error: No default glossary type (have you used nomain'?).`, and after removing `nomain` it works fine.

Comment: Exactly, thank you very much. As I remove nomain option, I can compile succesfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have pointed out the problem comes from using `nomain` (which prevents the main glossary from being created) but you haven't provided an alternative glossary (via package options such as `acronym` or explicitly using `\newglossary`).

It looks like you actually want the `acronym` option with `\newacronym` rather than `\newglossaryentry`. Like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{sk001}
\title{My title}

\usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{iai}{IAI}{Institut Africain d'Informatique}

\begin{document}

L'\gls{iai} est un établissement d'enseignement supérieur.
Next use: \gls{iai}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Note that since you're not using the main glossary, you need to specify the glossary in the optional argument of `\printglossary`. Alternatively you can just use `\printglossaries`, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{sk001}
\title{My title}

\usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{iai}{IAI}{Institut Africain d'Informatique}

\begin{document}

L'\gls{iai} est un établissement d'enseignement supérieur.
Next use: \gls{iai}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Or, with at least version 4.0, you can use `\printacronyms`, which is the same as `\printglossary[type=acronym]`.

Both the above examples produce:

[image: Image of result]

Other notes:

1. You don't need `section=chapter` in the package option as that's the default for classes that define `\chapter`
2. If you're just starting out with `glossaries`, I don't recommend using `nowarn` as it will suppress warnings that occur with some common new user mistakes. If you read those warnings, it may save you having to come back for more help.

Other resources:

- [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms).
- [Creating Glossaries, Lists of Symbols or Acronyms](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/makeglossaries.html)
- [glossaries FAQ](http://dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is very clear and explicit. Thank very much @Nicola Talbot