# Problems with glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I'm going to use a lot of definitions in my work, so I want to create the glossary. I've found the example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Glossary_definitions) .

I have a file `words.tex` where definitions are situated:

```
\newglossaryentry{r0}{name=\glslink{R0}{\ensuremath{R_{0}}},text=F\"{o}rster distance,description={F\"{o}rster distance, where 50\% ...}, sort=R}
\newglossaryentry{kdeac}{name=\glslink{R0}{\ensuremath{k_{DEAC}}},text=$k_{DEAC}$, description={is the rate of deactivation from ... and emission)}, sort=k}
\newacronym{ddye}{D$_{\text{dye}}$}{donor dye, ex. Alexa 488}
\newacronym[description={\glslink{r0}{F\"{o}rster distance}}]{R0}{$R_{0}$}{F\"{o}rster distance}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook} 
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

     \usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % Гиперссялки
     \hypersetup{
        colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = MidnightBlue,
        urlcolor = [rgb]{0,0,1},
        citecolor = red
     }
    ...

    \usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex

    \loadglsentries[main]{words}

    \begin{document} 


    \glsaddall
    \appendix
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{bibtex}
    \printindex
    \printglossaries
    \end{document}
```

When I'm trying to compile it, I get it:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary type `main' has not been defined.

See the glossaries package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ...{o}rster distance, where 50\% ...}, sort=R}

? H
You need to define a new glossary type, before making entries in it
```

What should I do? I'm searching similar topics, for example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152851/errors-when-using-glossaries-package). However, I haven't understood how this topic is related to me.

I hope you will help me:)

Comment: We'll try to help you.  :-)  That said, the code you posted is probably more involved than it needs to be.  Try trimming it down, and read about minimal working examples (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `nomain` from the options you pass the package. If you use this, you have to define specific glossaries and assign entries to them - there is no default glossary, `main`. If you remove the option, everything will be added to the default glossary unless otherwise specified, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Okay, I've corrected it.
But I have an error when `makeglossaries  main`:
`xindy  -L russian -C utf8 -I xindy -M "main" -t "main.alg" -o "main.acr" "main.acn"`
`Opening logfile "main.alg"` 
`ERROR: Opening logfile "main.alg" failed!`

    ***Call to xindy failed***